# Handling struct functions in C - Can enter an array but not an int

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having a bit of trouble with using structs inside functions.

The program is meant to:

1. Create an array containing five structures of type Person
2. Allow the user to enter the datatypes through use of functions.
3. Print the five entered people one by one.

While point 1 and 3 work fine, it's point 2 that I'm having issues with. The name will enter and print just fine, but regardless of what I enter into scanf it returns and prints '-858993460'.

```
int calls = 0;

typedef struct person {
    char name[20];
    int bYr;
}Person;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Person psn[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Please enter the name and birthyear of person %d.", i+1);
        personName(psn[i].name);
        personBirthyear(psn[i].bYr);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printPerson(psn[i]);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int personBirthyear(int birthyear) {
    printf("\nBirthyear: ");
    scanf("%d", &birthyear);
    getchar();
    return birthyear;
}

char* personName(char* pername) {
    printf("\nName: ");
    fgets(pername, 20, stdin);
    return pername;
}

void printPerson(Person prsn) {
    printf("Person %d:\nBirthyear: %d\nName: %s\n", calls+1, prsn.bYr, prsn.name);
    calls++;
}
```

Comment: Pass by value vs pass by reference. There are plenty of dupes out there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to pass by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007607/when-to-pass-by-value)

Comment: @John3136 agreed but the title often doesn't match. I flagged one at random. Hoping someone dupehammers it.

Comment: That's C. Not C++. And the question is not about "should I pass by value/pointer/reference" but "why is that failing". The asker is probably beginning at C, not learning how to do well in C.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough: you are not updating a `Person`' year, but you are passing it as a **copied argument** (you copy an `int` in `personBirthyear` and a pointer to a `char` in `personName`).

Thus:

```
personName(psn[i].name); // works
personBirthyear(psn[i].bYr); // fails
```

You need to pass the address of year, and work with pointers here:

```
int personBirthyear(int* birthyear) {
    printf("\nBirthyear: ");
    scanf("%d", birthyear);
    getchar();
    return *birthyear;
}
```

Or, you could also remove the birth year:

```
int personBirthyear() {
    int birthyear;
    printf("\nBirthyear: ");
    scanf("%d", &birthyear);
    getchar();
    return birthyear;
}
```

Then: `psn[i].bYr = personBirthyear();`

In any case, you don't check the result of scanf; thus you don't know if you actually read a number. You should check it:

```
int n = scanf("%d", &birthyear);
getchar();
if (n != 1) return -1;
return birthyear;
```

The `getchar` is still mandatory to "clear" away the character that made `scanf` fail (otherwise, it would be reread again and again...).

Answer (score 0):

you have some problems in your code :

1. You are not receiving a output while returning from function.
2. Without function declaration compiler will confuse about function return type.
3. you should know if you want to accept modified data between function call, data should provide as pass by reference. in your program, you give data to personBirthyear() function as call by value.